# Object #<person> has no method 'carName'

Tags: javascript

So I'm getting this error; Object # has no method 'carName'
But I clearly do.
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SaTedrce)

I've also tried referencing the car's "model" property with

```
player.car.model
```

but that doesn't work, I get a type error. Any ideas? Do you need more info?

```
function person(name, car) {
    this.name = name;
    this.car = car;
    function carName() {
        return car.model;
    }
}

var player = new person("Name", mustang);
var bot = new person("Bot", mustang);
var bot2 = new person("Bot 2", mustang);

function makeCar(company, model, maxMPH, tireSize, zeroToSixty) {
    this.company = company;
    this.model = model;
    this.maxMPH = maxMPH;
    this.tireSize = tireSize;
    this.zeroToSixty = zeroToSixty;
}

var mustang = new makeCar("Ford", "Mustang GT", 105, 22, 8);
var nissan = new makeCar("Nissan", "Nissan 360z", 100, 19, 6);
var toyota = new makeCar("Toyota", "Toyota brandname", 95, 21, 7);
```

Comment: please clarify the question. right now it is very close to "it dont work, fix it"

Comment: @DoubleElite, please try to paste samples into the question (and make it as small as possible at the same time) instead of only providing link to some location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not have the method. It has a function that is local to the variable scope of the constructor.

To give each object the function, assign it as a property...

```
function person(name, car) {
    this.name = name;
    this.car = car;
    this.carName = function() {
        return this.car.model;
    };
}
```

Or better, place it on the `prototype` of the constructor...

```
function person(name, car) {
    this.name = name;
    this.car = car;
}

person.prototype.carName = function() {
    return this.car.model;
};
```

Also, `mustang` isn't initialized when you're passing it to the `person` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, one question though. Why would using the prototype constructor for the "person" function be better than having a property assigned to a function (The first approach). Aren't they doing the same thing? Because person would be inheriting the prototype constructor.

Comment: @DoubleElite: The only thing that objects inherit from the `person` constructor will be the properties that are on the prototype object. So when you place `carName` on `person.prototype`, all `person` objects created will share that function. If you do `this.carName = func...` inside the constructor, then each `person` object will be assigned a unique (though identical) function. Remember that in the `person` constructor, `this` is a direct reference to *the new object being constructed*. I have a feeling you may be accustomed to OOP in another language. If so, JS is likely very different.

Comment: Yea, I'm coming from Java, but I can definitely see there are some huge differences between Java, and javascript.

Comment: @DoubleElite: Yeah, I know very little Java, but I know their OOP philosophy is entirely different. JS isn't class based, but rather is prototypal. When you create an object from a constructor like `person`, that object has an internal reference to the `.prototype` object of the `person` constructor. So if you look for a property on your `person` object, but that property doesn't exist, it automatically looks to the constructor's prototype to see if it exists there. That's how it finds its `carName` function.